# Matrix completion: supplementary questions

Tags: matrices, matrix-completion

Continuation of the [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341528/70405), what is going to  happen if we change the some of the conditions. I write it as a quote from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341528/70405) and change the appropriate places which are underlined:

> I need to construct $\underline{k\leq n^2}$ positive semi-definite matrices, say
> $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^k$. Entries of these matrices are complex numbers.
>
> 1> Each matrices are of dimension $n^2\times n^2$.
>
> 2> I only know the $n\times n$ block at top left corner of each
> matrix.
>
> 3> $P_i$ is a projection operator. For time being, let us assume that
> they are of rank $\underline{r_i\leq n}$ for each $i$. Moreover  they are mutually
> orthonormal.
>
> 4> $\underline{\sum_{i=1}^{k}P_i=I_{n^2}}$ is the identity operator.

One possible simpler case is when $r_i=n$ for all $i$. I am having doubt that the answer is not going to extend for the above cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the spectral decomposition of the matrix and use the method stated in the answer of [the above question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/345390/28724).